# Flash Builder 4.6, Mobile, Dynamic load image into custom ItemRender

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mobile, builder

Where is good place to load image in custom itemrender for list. I try to do it in createChildren where i create my holder for image, but data is not set yet.. I think in data function is not ok, because is calinig every time when user scroll.

Comment: set data should be where this is done. If your renderer is recycled this will called and the new data object will be passed in. Images should most likely be loaded outside of your renderer and cached appropriately. If you're using Flex the Spark Image will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data/url to the image in `commitProperties`.

Comment: With an itemRenderer; I would strongly recommend doing so in either the set data or in a dataChange event handler.  There is no guarantee that commitProperties will be re-executed as the user scrolls through the list.

Comment: I set the data/url  in commitProperties and works fine. Thank you! :)

Comment: Just in case you didn't, call invalidateProperties in the setter of data to guarantee commitProperties get's called. data will be set when the list scrolls, and commitProperties accordingly. Setting properties directly in data will lead to bad code as soon as your item renderer gets more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what the image is and how it relates to your itemRenderer.  Here are a few options:

If your image will not change based on the data then create your image class in createChildren().  Set the property on it in the createChildren() method; if it is static.  If it is something that may change you may consider setting it in commitProperties().

If your image will change based on the data; then you should change it either in the set data method or in a dataChange event handler.  I prefer the latter, but that is just preference.  An itemRenderer is re-used as the list is scrolled.  So the data that your renderer represents changes with it; and so should your visual display.

If lots of the elements of your dataProvider may use the same image; you can write conditional logic to determine whether or not the image should be loaded again.  This would prevent the image from reloading again unnecessarily.